# SQl query help to get the correct data

Tags: sql, sql-scripts

I wanted to write script to return those customer_id from customer table with following condition.

1. The get date is between start_date and end_date on order table.
2. Then the count of customer_id  on order table after matching condition 1 is more than one.

On the example below,select query within the exist statement should only return customer_id 300.

Because even though count of customer id 100 is 2, one of its record's start and end date is not between get date()

And Customer id 200 has only one record so it should be out of the result too.

Note: I am joining  customer table because I have to pass customer name as a parameter from customer table

Order table

```
ID      Customer_id   Start_date         End_date
1       100           1/1/2012         12/31/2017
2       100           1/1/2012          1/1/2015
3       200           1/1/2012          1/1/2020
4       300           1/1/2012          12/31/2018
5       300           1/1/2015           1/1/2019
```

Customer  table

```
ID  Customer_id   Name  
1   100            Ram  
2   300           John  
3   200           Jamie
```

My Script

```
If exist ( 

Select o.customer_id            

    from order o            
join customer c         

    ``on o.customer_id = c.customer_id          
where o.customer_id in (Select r.customer_id            
from order r            
where get date () between r.start_date and r.end_date)          

    And c.name = 'Ram'      
    group by o.customer_id          
having count(o.customer_id) > 1)
```

Comment: It will return no data, as the end_date for customer 300 is "1/1/2019" which is not in range of GetDate(), the sub query will return a record with customer 200, which falls between the range of dates, but the main query condition is not satisfied, so nothing is returned. Does this help or you need more information ?

Comment: what if the date is 5/1/2019 instead of 1/1/2019 for customer 300.What do i need to change on the script just to make it return 300

Comment: just to make it return 300 convert the date as you mentioned, and use below subquery : Select Top 1 r.customer_id            
from [dbo].[Order] r        
where getdate() between CONVERT(datetime, r.Start_date) and CONVERT(datetime, r.End_date)

=> use order by r.Customer_id desc for 300 and order by r.Customer_id for 200. Let me know if this helps, so that I can give you detailed answer.

Comment: Also you need to make more changes as Customer 300 is not Ram and you are expecting 300 to be matched with Ram.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments please find below query to get customer Id 300:

```
SELECT
    O.Customer_id         
FROM [dbo].[Order] O           
JOIN [dbo].[Customer] C        
    ON O.Customer_id = C.Customer_id          
WHERE O.Customer_id = (SELECT TOP 1 R.Customer_id            
FROM [dbo].[Order] R
WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, r.Start_date) 
    and CONVERT(datetime, r.End_date)
ORDER BY R.Customer_id DESC)
--And c.name = 'Ram'  // As per Your Customer table this should be 'john'    
GROUP BY O.Customer_id          
HAVING COUNT(O.Customer_id) > 1
```

Customer table should be like below:

```
ID  Customer_id   Name  
1   100           John  
2   300           Ram  
3   200           Jamie
```

Once you make this change in database use this statement => 'And c.name = 'Ram''
else use (as per your table structure) => 'And c.name = 'John''

Which will give you below result :

[image]

This will give you desired result. Hope this helps!